# How do I customise the Unsubscribe link in SendGrid?

Tags: java, sendgrid

I wish customise the position of the default Unsubscribe link that is sent by Sendgrid.
I have configured Unsubscribe groups in sendgrid and I am sending groupId with ASM, I do see the Unsubscribe from this List| Manage Email Preferences link, but the thing is, this link is directly appended to the body of the email thus making it difficult for the receiver to understand whether it is a part of the email or not, is there a way to customise this link so that it at least looks as a separate part of the email content?

```
  ASM asmInst = new ASM();
                asmInst.setGroupId(mailGroupId);
                mail.setASM(asmInst);
                int[] groupsToDisplay = {mailGroupId};
                asmInst.setGroupsToDisplay(groupsToDisplay);
                mail.setTemplateId("d- 
   848281f0ab8f45a7bc0e1690442a8803");
            }
```

above is my java code, here the mail object refers to instance of Mail from com.sendgrid.Mail and the object already has subject, recipient, email body, etc. If I set the template id as above, the email received by the recipient does not contain any subject, or email body, it only has the subscribe module that is configured in the dynamic templates. Here is a screenshot of the email received.
[image]

If I don't set the templateId, the email received is proper but the unsubscribe links are directly attached to the email body. Here is the email without template

[image]

Comment: You can customise your emails either in the template editor in the SendGrid console or by sending your own custom HTML. What are you doing?

Comment: how do I send my own custom HTML for the Unsubscribe link, can you point me to their documentation? my code is just as follows, I create a new ASM instance and set my desired groupId to it and asm instance is set to the Mail instance of Sendgrid.

Comment: The docs are here: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#adding-an-unsubscribe-group-to-your-email

Comment: Got it, thanks for you help!

Comment: Hey friend, need another help, so I create a dynamic template, drag an unsubscribe module in the editor and saved it, in my code along with the email contents and other required parameters, the groupId, now I'm also sending the template Id but the email that is being sent contains only the unsubcribe module, it doesn't even have the subject now, I believe I'm missing something in the template here, as I can see the mail object contains all the information need along with the subject, content, so on. Do I also use the text module in the template?

Comment: What is the code you’re using to send this email? It’s a little hard for me to help you debug this without seeing what you’re doing.

Comment: @philnash I have edited the description hope this gives a more clear picture of my problem

Comment: What does the design of your email template look like?

Comment: my email template only has the unsubscribe module, is that the problem? I tried adding the text module as well but I'm not sure how do I set my email content to the text module, also how do I replace the subject?

Comment: Yes, your email template needs to include all your content that you want in the email. Read this doc on how to design a dynamic template: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: Hey, another question, do you know after how long does the unsubscribe link expire or it does not expire at all? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: I don’t imagine they do expire. I can’t find anything about expiry, but they are unique links and I can’t imagine why they would expire. Is there something specific you need with expiring links, or are you just checking?

Comment: No, just had the question on my mind, anyway thanks!